# How to organise text in boxes?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the following code:

```css
.date-and-time {
    width: 960px;
    height: 640px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}

.stages {
    width: 700px;
    height: 1173px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 15%;
    
}

.setlist {
    width: 800px;
    height: 960px;
    position: absolute;
}

.shop {
    width: 860px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
}

.booking{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p class="date-and-time">Located at Sydney Showground.
    Date: 19-24 July 2022</p>
</body>
<body>
    <p class="stages">With a total of 10 unique areas, there's something for everyone at Vaporfest!</p>
</body>
<body>
    <p class="setlist">Over 100 musical acts will be performing at Vapor-fest!</p>
</body>
<body>
    <p class="shop">Official Vaporfest merchandise is now available!</p>
</body>
<body>
    <p class="booking">There are a limited amount of Vaporfest tickets available, so now is the time to book!</p>
</body>
```

Look like this:

[image: Date and time, stages, setlist, and shop paragraphs organised in an off-centre 4-picture collage. The booking section has its own space]

while still maintaining the dimensions.

Thanks

Comment: Start from https://www.w3schools.com/html/. An HTML document can only have one body.

Comment: First, please show us what effort you made to get the desired results. Secondly as said by Ali Demirci, an HTML document should have only one body tag

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should only have 1 body tag for the entire page. Also, I wouldn't set absolute widths and heights to your `<p>` tags.

You could achieve this with 2 wrapping divs that act as columns, for example something like:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: <whatever height you want here>
}

.left-col {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.right-col {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}

.booking {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-col">
    <div class="date-and-time">Located at Sydney Showground. Date: 19-24 July 2022
    </div>
    <div class="setlist">Over 100 musical acts will be performing at Vapor-fest</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="stages">With a total of 10 unique areas, there's something for everyone at Vaporfest!</div>
    <div class="shop">Official Vaporfest merchandise is now available!</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="booking">There are a limited amount of Vaporfest tickets available, so now is the time to book!</div>
```

That should at least get your started.

Comment: +1
Thanks. This worked after a small bit of modification to my existing document and clearing up what the div elements are meant to be.

Comment: By the way, how do I add margins?

Comment: In CSS just add `margin: 10px`. Or, if you want to be specific `margin-left: 10px`

Comment: I'm using percentage values. How do I do it without them overlapping?

Comment: How do you mean? If your percentage doesnt exceed 100% you shouldn't overlap

Comment: How do I add margins and make sure the left and right columns don't overlap?

Comment: Oh, you could try set padding instead. Margin adds distance to the outside, padding adds distance to the inside

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for CSS Grid! Adapt the example below to your needs.

[Kevin Powell resource on CSS grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU)

[webdevsimplified resource on CSS Grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zBsdzdE4sM)

[Complete guide to CSS grid by csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.date-and-time {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
.stages {
  grid-row: span 4;
}
.setlist {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
.shop {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.booking {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="date-and-time">Located at Sydney Showground. Date: 19-24 July 2022</p>
  <p class="stages">With a total of 10 unique areas, there's something for everyone at Vaporfest!</p>
  <p class="setlist">Over 100 musical acts will be performing at Vapor-fest!</p>
  <p class="shop">Official Vaporfest merchandise is now available!</p>
  <p class="booking">There are a limited amount of Vaporfest tickets available, so now is the time to book!</p>
</body>
```